# How to remove an entry location for a particular reference of the glossary term?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using a custom command `\addacronym` which creates two glossary entries for each acronym:

- the main entry and
- a cross-reference from the abbreviation to the main entry.

I also had to redefine the `\glsseeitemformat` command to change the text of the cross-reference links to the long versions of the acronyms by calling `\acrlong`.

The problem is that this command adds a new entry location to the main glossary term. How can I avoid that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% A new command creates two glossary entries for each acronym (the main entry
% and a cross-reference from abbreviation to the main entry).
% Syntax: \addacronym[options]{label}{abbreviation}{long}{description}
\newcommand{\addacronym}[5][]{
  % Create the main glossary entry with \newacronym
  % \newacronym[key-val list]{label}{abbrv}{long}
  \newacronym[
    name={#4 (#3)},
    description={#5},
    #1 % pass additional options to \newglossaryentry
    ]
    {#2}{#3}{#4}
  % Create a cross-reference from the abbreviation to the main glossary entry by
  % creating an auxiliary glossary entry (note: we set the label of this entry
  % to '<original label>_auxiliary' to avoid clashes)
  \newglossaryentry{#2_auxiliary}{
    name={#3},
    sort={#3},
    description={\makefirstuc{#4}},
    see=[See:]{#2}
  }
}

% Change the text of the cross-reference links to long versions of the acronyms
\renewcommand*{\glsseeitemformat}[1]{\emph{\acrlong{#1}}.}

\addacronym
 {sample} % label
 {ABR} % abbreviation
 {long version of the acronym}
 {Description of the acronym}

\begin{document}

The first occurrence of the acronym would look like:
\gls{sample}.
Further occurrences would look like: \gls{sample}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

It produces two pages. First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

The entry location I want to remove is crossed-out in red.

Comment: Try using `\glsentrylong` instead of `\acrlong`. The former just displays the text associated with the long version without indexing it or creating a hyperlink. If you want a hyperlink you can use `\glshyperlink[\glsentrylong{sample}]{sample}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, your solution works like a charm. Thanks! Please, create an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\glsentrylong` just displays the text associated with the long version without indexing it or creating a hyperlink, so you can use `\glsentrylong` instead of `\acrlong`. If you want a hyperlink as well, you can use `\glsentrylong` in the optional argument of `\glshyperlink`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% A new command creates two glossary entries for each acronym (the main entry
% and a cross-reference from abbreviation to the main entry).
% Syntax: \addacronym[options]{label}{abbreviation}{long}{description}
\newcommand{\addacronym}[5][]{
  % Create the main glossary entry with \newacronym
  % \newacronym[key-val list]{label}{abbrv}{long}
  \newacronym[
    name={#4 (#3)},
    description={#5},
    #1 % pass additional options to \newglossaryentry
    ]
    {#2}{#3}{#4}
  % Create a cross-reference from the abbreviation to the main glossary entry by
  % creating an auxiliary glossary entry (note: we set the label of this entry
  % to '<original label>_auxiliary' to avoid clashes)
  \newglossaryentry{#2_auxiliary}{
    name={#3},
    sort={#3},
    description={\makefirstuc{#4}},
    see=[See:]{#2}
  }
}

% Change the text of the cross-reference links to long versions of the acronyms
\renewcommand*{\glsseeitemformat}[1]{\emph{\glshyperlink[\glsentrylong{#1}]{#1}}.}

\addacronym
 {sample} % label
 {ABR} % abbreviation
 {long version of the acronym}
 {Description of the acronym}

\begin{document}

The first occurrence of the acronym would look like:
\gls{sample}.
Further occurrences would look like: \gls{sample}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting glossary]