# Glossary: Remove the entry location in the glossar itself

Tags: glossaries

To create my glossary I use a mix of "normal" entries and custom dual entries that create an abbreviation and a normal entry.

My Problem: Every entry in the glossary (custom and normal) show the glossary itself as the first location.

How can I remove this location (see picture)?

Glossary on Page 1:

[image]

MWE:

```
% Document
% ====================
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{memoir}

%% Glossary
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
    \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
        description={#6},#1
    }
    \makeglossaries
    \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}    {#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\glsenablehyper
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gradle}
{
    name={Gradle},
    description={Groovy basiertes Build system.},
    first={Gradle}
}

\newdualentry{adv}              % label
    {ADV}                           % abbreviation
    {Algorithm \& Data Structure Visualizer}    % long form
    {Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit} % description

\begin{document}

% Glossary
% ====================

\printglossary[title=Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
\glsaddall

\chapter{Test}
\section{One}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor sit amet.

\chapter{Test2}
\section{TWO}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor \gls{adv}  amet.

\end{document}
```

p.s. my question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128651/how-to-remove-an-entry-location-for-a-particular-reference-of-the-glossary-term) but the solution provided there did not help me

Comment: You have `\glsaddall` on page 1, so all entries will have 1 in their location list.

Comment: thank you for your reply. removing \glsaddall only gets me so far. It does remove the location page 1 from the normal entry. However, I would like to remove the 1 from all entries. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\newdualentry` is faulty. First it includes `\makeglossaries`, which should only be used once and it should be placed before all definitions. You already have `\makeglossaries` in the preamble before the first `\newglossaryentry`, which is correct and is the only place where it should occur.

The acronym's long form includes `\glsadd`:

```
\newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
```

With the default acronym style, the long form is copied to the `description` field, which means that `\glsadd{gls-#3}` ends up in the glossary, which indexes that page in the glossary.

This dual entry command seems to create unnecessary duplication. It would be simpler and more compact to do something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\glsenablehyper
\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\newglossaryentry{gradle}
{
    name={Gradle},
    description={Groovy basiertes Build system},
    first={Gradle}
}

\newacronym
  [description={Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit}]
  {adv}% label
  {ADV}% abbreviation
  {Algorithm \& Data Structure Visualizer}    % long form

\begin{document}

% Glossary
% ====================

\printglossary[title=Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\chapter{Test}
\section{One}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor sit amet.

\chapter{Test2}
\section{TWO}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor \gls{adv}  amet.

\end{document}
```

The glossary now looks like:

[image: Glossar und Abkrzungsverzeichnis Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer (ADV) Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit. 3 Gradle Groovy basiertes Build system. 2, 3]

If you really want dual entries, then you need to remove `\glsadd` from the description:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\glsenablehyper
\makeglossaries

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {%
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
      description={#6},#1
  }%
  \newacronym[see={gls-#3},description={#5},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{gradle}
{
    name={Gradle},
    description={Groovy basiertes Build system},
    first={Gradle}
}

\newdualentry
  {adv}% label
  {ADV}% abbreviation
  {Algorithm \& Data Structure Visualizer}    % long form
  {Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit} % description

\begin{document}

% Glossary
% ====================

\printglossary[title=Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\chapter{Test}
\section{One}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor sit amet.

\chapter{Test2}
\section{TWO}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor \gls{adv}  amet.

\end{document}
```

It seems a bit strange to have the cross-reference tag as *Glossary:* within the glossary, so I've omitted it, which means the tag is obtained from the language-sensitive `\seename` instead.

[image: Glossar und Abkrzungsverzeichnis ADV Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer. 3, siehe Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit. 3 Gradle Groovy basiertes Build system. 2, 3]

The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package provides more flexibility and also provides an extra debugging setting which provides visual markup to show where the indexing is occurring. The above example can be adapted to use `glossaries-extra`. I've removed the `description={#5}` setting in the definition of `\newdualentry`, which means that the `\glsadd{gls-#3}` code at the end of the long form will also be present again in the glossary. With `dbug=showwrgloss`, this indexing is shown by a dot · highlighted below:

[image: image of glossary with centred dot circled]

Adding `description={#5}` back into the definition:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {%
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
      description={#6},#1
  }%
  \newacronym[see={gls-#3},description={#5},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}%
}
```

and doing a fresh build should now only show the · marker in the main document text. (Remember to remove `debug=showwrgloss` once you've finished debugging.)

Here's an alternative approach that uses [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) instead of `makeindex`/`xindy`. The entries are now defined in `.bib` format. For example, `entries.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualabbreviationentry{adv,
  short={ADV},
  long={Algorithm \& Data Structure Visualizer},
  description={Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit}
}

@entry{gradle,
  name={Gradle},
  description={Groovy basiertes Build system}
}
```

(Note that there's no awkward `\glsadd`, which is what's causing the interference in the earlier examples.)

The document now looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record% using bib2gls
]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}% glossaries-extra.sty

\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescabbreviation}{%
  \ifglsentryexists{dual.\glscurrententrylabel}%
  {, \glsseeformat{dual.\glscurrententrylabel}{}}{}%
}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  combine-dual-locations=dual
]

\begin{document}

% Glossary
% ====================

\printunsrtglossary % glossaries-extra.sty and bib2gls
 [title=Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\chapter{Test}
\section{One}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor sit amet.

\chapter{Test2}
\section{TWO}
Lorem \gls{gradle} dolor \gls{adv}  amet.

\end{document}
```

The document build is now (assuming the document is called `myDoc.tex`):

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you want visual separation between letter groups (either just as vertical separation or with the `...group` styles) then you need the `--group` (or `-g`) switch:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The glossary now looks like:

[image: Glossar und Abkrzungsverzeichnis ADV Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer, siehe Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer Algorithm & Data Structure Visualizer Produkttitel der vorliegenden Bachelorarbeit 3 Gradle Groovy basiertes Build system 2, 3]

The `combine-dual-locations=dual` option transfers the location list from the ADV abbreviation to the Algorithm \& Data Structure Visualizer entry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Great explanation. I tried your second approach. It works great the first time. So I'm going to accept your answer. Any ideas why recompiling the glossary adds page 1 to the entries (dual) again?